# React Router Redirecting when not supposed to

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm protecting some of my routes in the `App.js` component by doing this:

```
<Route path="/backoffice/utilizadores">
 {role && (role === ADMIN || role === MOD) ? (
    <BackOfficeUsers />
   ) : (
    <Redirect to="/backoffice" />
   )}
</Route>
```

It works fine if I'm navigating by clicking on one of the `Link` of the navigation bar but when I type the address it redirects me even though the `role` is ADMIN. 
`role` comes from the redux store and this is declared at the beginning of my `App.js` component function declaration:

```
const role = useSelector((state) => state.auth.role);
```

I think this might have something to do with role being undefined or `""` when the `Route` loads but I'm not sure and I'm looking for some insight and a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

`AdminRoute.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

const AdminRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {
    const role = useSelector((state) => state.auth.role);
    // or const role = localstorage.getItem('role');

    return (

        // Show the component only when the user is logged in
        // Otherwise, redirect the user to /signin page
        <Route {...rest} render={props => (
            (role && (role === 'ADMIN' || role === 'MOD')) ?
                <Component {...props} />
            : <Redirect to="/backoffice" />
        )} />
    );
};

export default AdminRoute;
```

```
<AdminRoute path="/backoffice/utilizadores" component={BackOfficeUsers} />
```

Comment: Thank you but this didn't work. It keeps redirecting me to the `/backoffice` page.

Comment: I think you have to save role to localstorage when you login. then try again.

Comment: or I think try again like this `role === 'ADMIN' || role === 'MOD'` 
I think ADMIN & MOD is string value

Comment: Yes I declared them as `const` that are those exact strings :) unfortunately it still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It's a client routing  problem, so basically what happens is when you go to some page on your website besides index page, your javascript that gets your user/role is not executed. There are a few ways to fix this, easiest way would be to use the hash router. Hash router creates urls that are not the index page prefixed by a # and it doesn't read whatever follows that until index page code hasn't executed

EDIT:
Alternatively you can check this question out, it explains it so much better than I could ever so hope it helps

[React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :) but hash router is not really an option at the moment.

Comment: Hey, check the question I linked, hope it helps, I know routing can be really annoying, trust me :)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by declaring my routes in `App.js` like this:

```
<Route path="/backoffice/utilizadores">
 <BackOfficeUsers />
</Route>
```

and doing this on my navigation bar component:

```
const history = useHistory();
const role = useSelector((state) => state.auth.role);

useEffect(() => {
  if (
   history.location.pathname.includes("/backoffice/") &&
   (role !== "ADMIN" || role !== "MOD")
  ) {
    history.replace("/home");
  }
}, [history.location.pathname, role]);
```

I still don't fully understand what was happening and why my previous solution wasn't working properly.